# Where are our migration options?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, migration

In closing question section, we are not showing a migration list.

[image]

Like stack-overflow.

[image]

Similarly in http://scifi.stackexchange.com movies and TV not coming in there migration list.

Both SF&F and M&TV are graduate and can bring cross post, so is it not good to provide them as migration option on each other site to make the migration handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pose a good suggestion, but let's look at this a little closer. We can take a look at our off-migrations [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away) (well, 10kers at least). This shows that over the entire lifetime of the site we have migrated a whole lot of **29** questions away from us, to the following sites:

- [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/): 13
- [Movies & TV meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/): 6
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/): 3
- [Anime and Manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/): 2
- [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/): 2
- and some others with a single migration.

So **migration away from here doesn't seem a particularly common event**, occuring 7 times in 2014. This means, a migration path doesn't really seem necessary, since there is no need in artificially rising the frequency of migrations. A migration should really only be done if the question is entirely **off-topic** here and **not** if it would just maybe get a *"better answer"* over at another site. If an asker explicitly wishes his question migrated, then he can always flag it for moderator attention and ask his question to be moved over.

The reason why there is in turn no migration path to us on *Science Fiction and Fantasy* is elaborated in [this related question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4700/23386) and is due to the fact that many users over there are unclear about the intricacies of things being on/off-topic on *Science Fiction and Fantasy* and would thus be inclined to vote for migration more often than actually necessary. So it would thus be better for them to **leave the migration decision upto the moderators' discretion** once something is clearly off-topic instead of making it a community vote.

I don't know if we would face the same problems with users prematurely voting for valid questions to be migratd away (though, *iandotkelly*'s insight as an actual moderator, as presented in his below comment, could suggest so), but for now **migration paths just don't seem necessary** anyway, since the currently less than 1 migration per month seems tacklable by explicit moderator decisions without any problems.

Comment: I cannot reiterate the "maybe get a 'better answer'" point enough.  I regularly get flags suggesting migration for perfectly on-topic questions.

Comment: @iandotkelly Now this is valuable insight from you as a moderator (and might confirm what I had feared, even if not believed, afterall). Though, how's your comment supposed to be understood? Can you *not* reiterate that point (even though your experiences support it) or *can* you reiterate it (or what is *"reiterate"* supposed to mean here)?

Comment: Fixed it for you.

Comment: Just saying: It's possible that the number of migrations is so low _because_ there are no migration paths. There is no easy way for the community to migrate something, hence no migrations. But yeah I still concur with the rest of your post.

Comment: @atticae Well, that may be, but this is actually a good thing. Judging from memory, I don't think there was anything that was closed but not migrated which should have been migrated. And those are the only ones where migration is appropriate. All the other supposedly missed migrations would then be ones where the migration was *not* preceded by closing and those are inappropriate ones anyway.

Comment: @atticae - there were migration paths until we graduated.  I don't actually know why we don't have any now.   So the number of migrations was not that low for that reason.

Comment: @iandotkelly Oh really, didn't know that. So it wasn't misused that much afterall.